# Jquery string match with regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

want to search the text and get the no of matches :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchText(text) {
            var pattern = new RegExp("/" + text + "/g");
            var totalMatchCount = ($('Test').text().match(pattern) || []).length;
            alert(totalMatchCount)
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="Test">

        2015-11-05 22:01:00,062                      WARN  [] (Thread-1169 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license you are using has expired or is bad.  value: -5
        2015-11-05 22:02:00,026                      WARN  [] (Thread-1165 (-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license you are using has expired or is bad.  value: -5
        2015-11-05 22:03:00,049                      WARN  [] (Thread-1180 (-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license you are using has expired or is bad.  value: -5
    </div>

    <button onclick="searchText('WARN')">Search</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm searching for `WARN` word and used `RegExp()` method for pattern,
but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Issues:

1. Change `var pattern = new RegExp("/" + text + "/g");` to `var pattern = new RegExp(text, "g");` `RegExp` expect the flags to be used as second parameter
2. Incorrect selector. `$('Test').text().`. No id selector used `$('#Test').text().`

```js
function searchText(text) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(text, "g");
  var totalMatchCount = ($('#Test').text().match(pattern) || []).length;

  console.log(totalMatchCount);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify($('#Test').text().match(pattern), 0, 4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Test">

  2015-11-05 22:01:00,062 WARN [dms.framework.licensing.LicenseManager] (Thread-1169 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license you are using has expired or is bad. value: -5 2015-11-05 22:02:00,026 WARN [dms.framework.licensing.LicenseManager]
  (Thread-1165 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license you are using has expired or is bad. value: -5 2015-11-05 22:03:00,049 WARN [dms.framework.licensing.LicenseManager] (Thread-1180 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-643998766)) The license
  you are using has expired or is bad. value: -5 2015-11-05 22:04:00,029
</div>

<button onclick="searchText('WARN')">Search</button>

<hr />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, I am not aware of first issue. Its working as expected